# Static content deploy issue

Tags: magento2, css, deploy

I am creating a custom theme. Now I *added a css file, only for checkout page*.

css file call by ***default_head_block.xml*** at  ***app/design/frontent/Amit/Customtheme/Magento_Checkout/layout/***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Magento_Checkout::css/checkoutstyle.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Css file ***checkoutstyle.css*** location is ***app/design/frontent/Amit/Customtheme/Magento_Checkout/web/css***.

Now when I try to deploy that css file using `php  bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

**I get this error:**

```
Compilation from source: 
frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/styles-l.less
variable @checkout-tooltip-icon__font-size is undefined in file /var/www/html/Amit/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/source/_extends.less in _extends.less on line 1056, column 21
1054|     input {
1055|         .lib-css(margin-right, @indent__s);
1056|         width: calc(~"100% - (@{checkout-tooltip-icon__font-size} + @{indent__s} + @{indent__xs})");
1057|     }
1058| }
1059| >
```

**Note:  Current application mode: developer** and system is Ubuntu.

Can any one tell me what is happen?

Comment: Can any one tell m why is down vote?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Solution is deprecated: Do not Not used it. Bad idea to switch to default

It got a solution, which may not be 100% right.

- First I change **change current application** mode to **default** from  `developer` at *app/etc/env.php* `['MAGE_MODE' => 'developer' to 'MAGE_MODE' => 'default']`.
- Also,Manually by **clearing** the `pub/static` and `var/view_preprocessed`
  directories and subdirectories. except for `pub/static/.htaccess`
- Then run  `php  bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`  and it
  **successfully generate static files**.
- And change **Change current application** `developer` and  run `php  bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`  and it successfully
  generate static files again.

**Hope this will help anyone.**

Comment: how did you change the application back to default from developer?

Comment: app/etc/env.php ['MAGE_MODE' => 'developer' to 'MAGE_MODE' => 'default']

Comment: Great solution. I did the same as Amit suggested & got working. One thing I would like to add.....that......I performed the first step developer to default then 2nd step pub/static & var/view_preprocessed then ran command deploy.....at this time error did not go off.....it was still there but then I again changed the mode to developer from default. Then again ran the deploy command & then the error solved :)  Whatever it may be but Amit's solution worked for me :)  Thanks Amit :)

Comment: Hi Amit, i have tried your solution, still error exists...Here is my error msg:Compilation from source: /opt/lampp/htdocs/khelkart/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-inline.less

Compilation from source: 
frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/email-inline.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

.................................................................................................
Successful: 1411 files; errors: 14

can u please help me in solving this issue

Comment: It did not work for me!

Comment: Sort of worked for me, except I was already in default mode and switched to developer, then cleared var/view_preprocessed and pub/static except htaccess and the errors went away. Maybe the mode doesn't matter as much as clearing those folders?

Comment: Good job on reiterating your comment!

Comment: @AmitBera Then what is the new solution?

Comment: I am facing Compilation from source: LESS file is empty issue after magento upgrade from 2.3.3  to 2.3.5 EE at the time of Static content deploy can you help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved this issue (still within developer mode):

- Make a copy of your theme
- Delete theme from server
- Switch back to Luma within admin
- Clean cache, remove static files and var/view_preprocessed

  ```
  rm -rf pub/static/frontend/* var/view_preprocessed
  bin/magento c:c
  bin/magento c:f
  ```
- run deploy command

  ```
  bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
  ```
- then re-upload your theme and switch it on within admin
- run deploy again

  ```
  bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
  ```

Comment: It dosn't make sense but after 2 days cleaning all sort of folders and files, I followed your instructions and it work, thanks, the crazy thing is that i have exactly the same repo and db in another 5 envs and i only had the issue in one envirourment

Answer (score 0):

Go to /var/www/html/Amit/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/source/_extends.less in _extends.less

and on the top add `@checkout-tooltip-icon__font-size: 18px;`

Comment: are u sure about this because of  view_preprocesed  is create  during cache/deploy

Comment: You can directly add this code on blank theme. Then delete view_preprocessed. and run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 0):

Solution worked for me after updating Magento 2.2.5 to 2.3.2:

turns out if there is something missing in the lib folder, this will never recover. In order to do so, download a fresh copy of Magento and replace the lib folder.

After replacing I got this error :

```
Autoload error: Library 'magento/framework' from '/var/www/html/luiz/lib/internal/Magento/Framework' has been already defined in '/var/www/html/luiz/vendor/magento/framework'
```

Then I have deleted the folder lib/internal/Magento from Magento root directory.

```
rm -rf lib/internal/Magento

rm -rf var/cache var/page_cache var/view_preprocessed pub/static/*
```

After all of this, I have run:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

please notice, if you are in developer mode it is ok, but if you are in default or production run this:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

And of course you can use the following commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --jobs 3
```

where jobs 3 -> means number of threads to use for your deploy process.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US de_DE--jobs 3
```

You can use languages inline without any troubles.