# Issues with deplyoing static files command and frontend loses css and js

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.3

I have a serious issue which is ongoing with running

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

First, I installed `Magento 2.1.3`  by uploading the files and run the setup wizard, all went fine, installed my theme and created a custom theme and all went fine whilst using the command etc.

But at some point, for whatever reason, the command ends up throwing many errors. The frontend has also lost functionality too.

The errors are are as follows in the console and sytemm.log, too many related to all themes active such as blank and luma:

[image]

I have checked a few resources and followed the instructions but no luck, some followed are:

1) https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2273

2) [Static content deploy issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108919/static-content-deploy-issue)

3) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37964713/not-able-to-deploy-static-content-magento2-0

4) How to fix the problem of loading css and javascript files?
Login to ssh, go to magento directory for instance I'm

```
cd /var/www/html/magento
```

- 1: Removed follwoing folders via running

  - rm -rf var/di/*
  - var/generation/*
  - var/cache/*
  - var/page_cache/*
  - var/view_preprocessed/*
  - var/composer_home/cache/*
- 2: sudo chmod 777 var -R
- 3: sudo chmod 777 pub -R
- 4: `sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
- 5: Repeat step 2 & 3.

And some others I found on google but no resolution to the issue.

Please help me, as it is urgent for me to resolve this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would also check ownership of files and folders, when I delete pub/static or var/cache on my server they new files created belong to apache, and are not accessible. Still trying to figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

that is wired, It is file/directory ownership related issue, faced this issue while we run the command cache:clean and it gives error when you try to deploy static content again.