# I can't figure out this CSS / less issue that is blowing up my exception.log

Tags: magento2, log, less-css

Any idea why this keeps going nuts in my exception.log

```
[2019-02-18 22:08:35] report.CRITICAL: .lib-font-size is undefined in /srv/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/website/en_US/css/base-extend.less {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\View\\Asset\\ContentProcessorException(code: 0): .lib-font-size is undefined in /srv/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/website/en_US/css/base-extend.less at /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Css/PreProcessor/Adapter/Less/Processor.php:97)"} []

[2019-02-18 22:41:21] report.CRITICAL: .lib-font-size is undefined in /srv/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/website/en_US/css/base-extend.less {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\View\\Asset\\ContentProcessorException(code: 0): .lib-font-size is undefined in /srv/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/website/en_US/css/base-extend.less at /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Css/PreProcessor/Adapter/Less/Processor.php:97)"} []

[2019-02-18 22:41:21] report.CRITICAL: .lib-font-size is undefined in /srv/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/website/en_US/css/base-extend.less {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\View\\Asset\\ContentProcessorException(code: 0): .lib-font-size is undefined in /srv/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/website/en_US/css/base-extend.less at /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Css/PreProcessor/Adapter/Less/Processor.php:97)"} []
```

I don't have to much more to offer. It just started happening and it's writing to the exception log and filling it up really quick.

Answer (score 0):

This exception clearly mentioned it is came from `/srv/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/` so you need to remove that folder.

Run the below command in the magento root directory.

```
rm -rf var/page_cache var/view_preprocessed var/cache
```

I hope it fixed the issue.

Comment: That didn't work, the first time i tried to remove i got this error: rm: cannot remove 'var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/website': Directory not empty. Then i tried it again and it looks like it removed them but i'm still getting the error. @Bilal USean

Comment: post your new error.

Comment: @Supplement look at this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/109048/36463